# I am trying to identify a component next to a high-voltage output

Tags: identification, components

I am having a hard time finding a component and its value. Can anyone tell from the image?

The component, that is some type of coil/transformer/choke, sits right next to a 2500 V high-voltage output. That output is powering a 1000 W halogen bulb.

It has 6 pins, and on one of the circuitboards it was so damaged that I could see inside it. It has one thicker wire with one turn on one side, and more turns with thinner copper on the other. There also was a magnetic core.

I have tried to search for the markings "VOGT V8" but cannot find anything that resembles this.

The circuit board is powered by 400 V (orange connector) and I think it could be around 20 years old.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Halogen or HID?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany could the ignition coil be this small?

Comment: Yes it is a HID.

Comment: I think VOGT was purchased by Sumida. But the part may be obsolete by now.

Comment: I have more boards, and found one with another marking: https://imgur.com/a/bq1Ex5a

Comment: After some more research, i tought i was looking for a trigger coil. But then i found this text for exactly this board: "GreenVision electronic gear for MASTER Green Power 600 and 1000W EL does not use ignition pulses. Instead a sinusoidal ignition voltage of maximum 2600 (600W) and 2400 (1000W) Vrms is used." Does that say something about what it is?

Comment: I sant an email to Sumida, they confirmed that the component was specially custom made for a customer and that they could not tell anything more about it.